# python with javascript 

Tags: javascript, python, html, mechanize

I am working on parsing a html page.

I tried spynner, selenium, mechanize but didnt able to solve issue with javascript with this case.
Can anyone let me know how can i work with such issue to fetch the data to next page?

when I worked on selenium, in this url first we have to get the data in other select box and then proceed but using selenium I am able to get only same url after click on the next page,
same incase of spynner too.

Comment: Have you debugged the original javascript code of the page? E.g. is there any code binded to onclick() event of the link/button that directs to the next page?

Comment: why down-voted unnecessary? I have already tried and after tried I have pasted the link.

Comment: My guess is that the reason you were voted down is because you really haven't showed anything you have tried other than listing libraries you claim didn't work for you. There is no code attempts or errors to address. Why didn't Selenium work? I didn't vote you down btw. This is just my guess. People on SO don't like to see questions that say "I have tried XYZ but they all failed...Please help"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, mechanize doesn't support javascript.  So, if you're doing any automation with javascript heavy sites, mechanize is probably not the way to go.  Rather, you probably need python to script a fully functional web browser.  You can do this with Mozilla via [PyXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/PyXPCOM), with [Ruby and WATIR](http://watir.com/), or with [spynner](http://code.google.com/p/spynner/).  Of these options, I'd probably try spynner, first, as spynner is well integrated with python.

Good luck with your project, and happy coding!